# My linked list is giving segmentation faults after i delete an element and try to display my phone book

Tags: c, struct, singly-linked-list, strcmp, function-definition

I'm trying to create a telephone directory and I'm having issues with my delete_pr function. the function's name itself explains what it is supposed to do pretty much. When I create a record using create_pd it works, and then I use the display function and then it displays the created record. Then when I try to use the delete_pr function and type in my number, then it deletes the last element when I use the display function afterward and I get a segmentation fault. One thing I came up with is that maybe my pointers are not implemented correctly in the delete function?. Thanks beforehand I really appreciate any sort of help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct phonedir 
{
    char* name;
    char* phonenum;
    struct phonedir *next;

};


struct phonedir *start = NULL;

void display();
struct phonedir *create_pd(struct phonedir *);
struct phonedir *insert_beg(struct phonedir *);
struct phonedir *delete_pr(struct phonedir *);


int main ()
{
    int option;
    while (option != 5)
    {
        printf("\n\n *****MAIN MENU *****");
        printf("\n 1: Create a record");
        printf("\n 2: Display the records");
        printf("\n 3: insert a new record");
        printf("\n 4: Delete a record");
        printf("\n 5: EXIT");
        printf("\n\n Enter your option : ");
        scanf("%d", &option);
        switch(option)
        {
            case 1: start = create_pd(start);
            printf("\n PHONE RECORD CREATED");
            break;
            case 2: display(start);
            break;
            case 3: start = insert_beg (start);
            printf("PHONE RECORD ADDED \n");
            break;
            case 4: start = delete_pr(start);
            break;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}

void display()
{
    struct phonedir *ptr;

    printf("\t\t THE RECORDS\n");

    ptr = start;
    while(ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("\t phonenumber: %s\n", ptr -> phonenum);
        printf("\t name: %s\n", ptr -> name);
        ptr = ptr -> next;
    }
}

struct phonedir *create_pd(struct phonedir *start)
{
    struct phonedir *new_phonedir, *ptr;
    new_phonedir = (struct phonedir *)malloc(sizeof(struct phonedir));

    new_phonedir->phonenum = (char *)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    new_phonedir->name = (char *)malloc(80*sizeof(char));

    printf("Enter the phone number: \n");
    scanf("%s", new_phonedir->phonenum);
    printf("Enter name: \n");
    scanf("%s", new_phonedir->name);

    if (start == NULL)
    {
        new_phonedir->next= NULL;
        start = new_phonedir;

    }
    else
    {
        ptr = start;
        while(ptr->next != NULL)
        {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        ptr->next = new_phonedir;
        new_phonedir->next = NULL;

    }
    return start;
}



struct phonedir *insert_beg(struct phonedir *start)
{
    
    struct phonedir *new_phonedir;

    new_phonedir = (struct phonedir *)malloc(sizeof(struct phonedir));

    new_phonedir->phonenum = (char *)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    new_phonedir->name = (char *)malloc(80*sizeof(char));

    printf("Enter phone number: \n");
    scanf("%s", new_phonedir->phonenum);
    printf("Enter name: \n");
    scanf("%s", new_phonedir->name);

    new_phonedir ->next = start;
    start = new_phonedir;
    return start;

}

struct phonedir *delete_pr(struct phonedir *start)
{
    struct phonedir *preptr,*ptr;
    char *num;

    printf("Enter phone number of the record to be deleted: \n");
    scanf("%s", num);

    ptr = start;
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        preptr = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;

        if(ptr->phonenum == num)
        {
            preptr->next = ptr->next;
            free(ptr);
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            ptr = ptr->next;
            preptr = preptr->next;
        }
    }

    return start;
}
```

Comment: When `ptr` points to the last node, `ptr = ptr->next;` sets it to `NULL`. Then you try to do `if (ptr->phonenum == num)` and that dereferences a null pointer.

Comment: `char *num` is not initialized at the call `scanf("%s", num);`.

Comment: You cannot use `==` to compare strings. Use `strcmp`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an uninitialized pointer to read data

```
struct phonedir *delete_pr(struct phonedir *start)
{
    struct phonedir *preptr,*ptr;
    char *num;

    printf("Enter phone number of the record to be deleted: \n");
    scanf("%s", num);
    //...
```

So this invokes undefined behavior.

This if statement

```
 if(ptr->phonenum == num)
```

will always evaluate to false because there are compared pointers with different values. You need to compare pointed strings like

```
 if( strcmp( ptr->phonenum, num ) == 0 )
```

But the first node was already skipped due to the preceding statement

```
ptr = ptr->next;
```

Moreover after this statement `ptr` can be equal to `NULL` that again invokes undefined behavior.

And the function has the return type `struct phonedir *`

```
struct phonedir *delete_pr(struct phonedir *start)
```

and you are returning a null pointer

```
    if(ptr->phonenum == num)
    {
        preptr->next = ptr->next;
        free(ptr);
        return 0;
    }
```

that is assigned to the pointer `start` in main

```
case 4: start = delete_pr(start);
```

As a result the pointer `start` can be invalid and there can be numeric memory leaks.

Using your approach the function can be defined for example the following way

```
struct phonedir * delete_pr(struct phonedir *start)
{
    char num[20];

    printf("Enter phone number of the record to be deleted: ");
    
    if ( scanf( "%19s", num ) == 1 )
    {    
        struct phonedir *preptr = NULL, *ptr = start;

        while ( ptr != NULL && strcmp( ptr->phonenum, num ) != 0 )
        {
            preptr = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }

        if ( ptr != NULL )
        {
            if ( preptr == NULL )
            {
                start = ptr->next;
            }
            else
            {
                preptr->next = ptr->next;
            }

            free( ptr );
        }
    }  

    return start;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but the issue here is that my delete function should return either 0 if successful and -1 otherwise, and its going to to use a search function that is going to check is the number exists or not. One thing as well is that I should use the phone no as an input parameter.

Comment: @ghadds What you have written now contradicts to the code you provided in the question. The function is declared like struct phonedir *delete_pr(struct phonedir *); So it returns  neither integer.